# Ciphertext on server

Tags: security, cryptography, protocols

Are there any protocols which would allow 2 visitors to communicate securely through my website, without the possibility of me reading their messages?

Answer (score 3):

Ask Google for End-to-End encryption like PGP/GPG. For a client-side browser-based implementation you might want to check out [GPG encryption in JavaScript](http://www.hanewin.net/encrypt/).

I just googled it and cannot tell if its really secure (not sending your private key to anyone). I just want to give you a point to start with.

**EDIT:** Looks like it **does** send the clients private key to your server to perform a server-based encryption. This is **not** what you want. But I am sure that a JavaScript implementation of GPG is possible even though I don't know if somebody has done it yet.

Comment: There are some issues with using Javascript for encryption. You may want to consider the points raised in this article before using a javascript solution: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Answer (score 2):

Yes; for example, this is what would happen if your server was a link in a communication protected by SSL/TLS.
The participants use a public-key encryption scheme to agree upon a secret, symmetric key; that is then used to encrypt their communication.

It's also possible for the participants to simply encrypt their messages with the public key of the intended receiver. That way, only the intended receiver can decrypt the message. This is not a very advanced scheme and probably vulnerable. (Among others, if an eavesdropper can guess *exactly* what is sent, he can encrypt that message with the intended recipient's public key and see if the result matches with what is being sent).

There is a lot of literature available on cryptographic protocols; for starters, here's a Wikipedia article on [Key Agreement Protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_agreement).

Comment: Would using TLS mean that both users would need to be online? I want to actually store the messages.

Comment: No, you could use the same algorithm for exchanging a symmetric key, regardless of when the participants are logged in - as long as the steps are taken in the right order.

Comment: @destructo_gold If you store the messages on your server I strongly recommend using PGP. It was designed to encrypt email which is pretty much the same use case. However, users will have to permanently save some data (private keys) on their machines.

Comment: I want to use PGP ideally, so that keys can be certified, however I don't know of any browser-based implementations of it?

Comment: Your example shows why text-book RSA is not semantically secure. In practice, RSA encryption is used with a random padding, which means the attacker would not only have to guess the message, but also guess (or brute-force) the random numbers used to generate the padding.  But RSA is normally not used anyways to directly encrypt a message, but to encrypt a symmetric key, which then is used with AES or similar for the actual message.

Answer (score 2):

If we're talking about **not possible** then the second part to S.L. Barth's answer will achieve this with the exception that the key exchange must be done by some other means.  This can be the phone or email or even another website but if it's done via your website then it's open to a [man-in-the-middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).  You can tell your users to do this, you just can't actually help them do it.

There is probably a javascript library somewhere that will implement GPG encryption so that all you have to do is make sure that every message is encrypted in the browser before it's sent to your web server.  You can store the messages as long as you like, they're encrypted.  Only the user with the correct private key will be able to decrypt it.

SSL and TLS as they are used by websites everywhere are vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks.  The reason we don't hear much about these sorts of attacks is that most of the people in the middle are trustworthy so the attacks simply don't happen.  The recent revoking of the CA certificates of [DigiNotar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigiNotar) and others was precisely because the Iranian Government were caught acting as a man-in-the-middle and decrypting their own citizen's SSL traffic.

If you're happy with preventing casual snooping by curious sysadmins, the key exchange can be done through your website as well.

One more thing: Security is hard.

Even if you do this with well-known encryption techniques, the chances of there being a flaw in the implementation will be very close to 1.  This doesn't mean that those curious sysadmins will be able to accidentally read messages but it does mean that a determined and skilled adversary will be able to find a way in.  As soon as you can afford it you should hire an expert to redesign or at the very least examine your protocol and implementation.

Comment: +1 even though I'm not that pessimistic about flaws in crypto implementations. Also I think that SSL and TLS are not vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks by design. It's all about who you trust.

Comment: @MBober SSL/TLS are designed for client-server communication, not client-server-client without the server reading anything. Of course, you could tunnel SSL over a pair of normal socket connections, but still the clients need some way of identifying each other.

Answer (score 0):

In general, such a secure link between your users without you being able to read and/or modify their messages is only possible if they have some way of identifying each other (or at least in one direction).

This might be a shared secret (like a passphrase) or a public key known to one (or certified by a CA known to one), where the other one has the corresponding private key.

On this one can build a secure protocol (using a key exchange and then symmetric encryption with MACs in both directions), like TLS does. (Another way, used often for instant messaging, is OTR, the [Off-the-Record messaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-the-Record_Messaging) protocol.)

Without a way to identify the other end point, you end up with a way of allowing man-in-the-middle attacks. SSL/TLS without certificates, or with certificates where the man-in-the-middle knows the corresponding private key, is insecure, as is every other similar encryption scheme.

Another issue is that you said *visitors of my website*. This looks like you would implement client-side cryptography in JavaScript, delivered from your website. Don't do this ... if the visitors do not trust you not to read their data, they also should not trust you to feed them non-malicious JavaScript, which might implement something else than you are claiming it does, again allowing a MITM, or even directly sending a copy of the data to you.

More details about this are discussed in [Javascript Cryptography Considered Harmful](http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/) (from a slightly different perspective).